# Splice string to get everything from the left of the first space and to the right of the right space

Tags: python

I have this string I want to splice "$14.79 to $39.79". What I want is to assign the $14.79 to its own string variable (already have logic to strip $ and convert to float) and the $39.79 to its own string variable. How do I do that? The dollar amounts may change (i.e, $560.95, $4.55, etc.) but the "space to space" will always be there no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

you can split you string by space's then remove the `to` string
like below code

```
currency = "$300 to $50000"

# split by space
splitted = currency.split(" ")

# remove to keyword
del splitted[1]

print(splitted)

# it will print a list ['$300', '$50000']
# you can join it or anything you want to do
```

or you can like this

```
currency = "$300 to $50000"

# split by space
splitted = currency.split(" ")

# remove to keyword
splitted.remove('to')

print(splitted)

# it will print a list again ['$300', '$50000']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = '$14.79 to $39.79'
v1, *_, v2 = s.split()
print(v1, v2)
```

Prints:

```
$14.79 $39.79
```

Or using `re` (this will remove `$` too):

```
import re
v1, v2 = re.findall('[\d.]+', s)
print(v1, v2)
```

Prints:

```
14.79 39.79
```